# Laravel 10 Undefined variable $journals & Target class [JournalController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I've been trying to fix the init error for hours but it still doesn't work. I've created a controller named JournalController.php

Why is my controller not working?

This is my code that error in "Target class [JournalController] does not exist". Actually on this page the display has appeared, but when the submit button is clicked. Then an error will appear that the Controller does not exist.

```blade
<form class="register-form" method="post" action="{{ route('journals.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <label>Post a Picture</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" id="formFile">

    <label>Place Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="place" value="{{ old('place') }}" placeholder="Neuschwanstein">

    <label>Country</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" value="{{ old('country') }}" placeholder="Jerman">

    <label>Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control"name="date" value="{{ old('date') }}">

    <label>Experiences</label>
    <input type="Text" class="form-control" name="experience" value="{{ old('experience') }}" placeholder="The most beautiful castle">

    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-round" type="submit" href="{{ route('journals.create') }}"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add</button>
</form>
```

This is my code that error in "Undefined variable $journals", The error is " @forelse ($journals as $journal)".

```blade
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Experiences</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @forelse ($journals as $journal)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $journal->id }}</td>
            <td><img src="{{ asset($journal->image) }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width:200px" />
            </td>
            <td>{{ $journal->place }}</td>
            <td>{{ $journal->country }}</td>
            <td>{{ $journal->date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $journal->experience }}</td>
        </tr>
        @empty
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">
              No record found!
          </td>
        </tr>
      @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my Controller, I've tried the various methods that I listed here. But it hasn't worked

```
public function index()
{
    $journals = Journal::get();

    return view('journals.index', ['journals' => $journals]);
    return view('journals.index', compact('journals'));
    return view('journals.index')->with('journals', $journals);

    return view('journals.index', ['journals' => Journals::all(),]);
}
```

Comment: `return view('journals.index', ['journals' => $journals]);` is the preferred syntax, but all 4 of the options you used should make `$journals` available in your view. As for your undefined `JournalController` issue, we need to see `JournalController` and `routes/web.php` to see how you've defined this Controller and how you're using it. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76649562/edit) and include both of those files please.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please update your question providing your `routes > web.config` to see what is going on with the controller and routing issue.

With the `Undefined variable` I tend to do the following when passing variables, even if there is just one as it looks better and if later down the line its easier to pass more variables.

```php
return view('your view here')->with([
    'journals' => $journals
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel cannot find the specified controller class. The file should be named "JournalController.php" and should include the following.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Journal;

class JournalController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $journals = Journal::get();

        return view('journals.index', ['journals' => $journals]);
    }
}
```

Make sure to clear the cached routes and if the issues persists try running the following command to optimize your application's autoload files:

```
php artisan route:cache

composer dump-autoload
```